# File not found when running a file in JupiterLab console

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Every time when I try to run a file in the JupiterLab console I get the following message:

ERROR:root:File `'thing.py'` not found.

In this case, my file is called  *thing.py*  and I try to run it with the trivial  *run thing.py*  command in the console. The code is running and it gives me correct results when executed in the console, but I wanted to have it saved, so I put it in a JupiterLab text file and changed the extension to *.py* instead of *.txt*. But I get the aforementioned message regardless of which file I try to run. I am new to JupiterLab and admit that I might have missed something important. Every help is much appreciated.

Comment: if you exectuce `ls` can you see the file?

Comment: you need to start the interpreter in the same directory as the file *or* you can navigate to that directory from inside the interpreter

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Jupyterlab you should be able:

1. to create a new file & paste in your commands

[image]

2. Rename that file to "thing.py"

[image]

3. And then open a console in the same Jupyterlab instance and run that file. Notice that you can see "thing.py" in the file explorer on the left:

[image]

4. Alternatively, you can use the `%load` magic command in a notebook to dynamically load the code into a notebook's cell.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You might want to understand exactly what a Jupyter Lab file is, and what a Jupyter Lab file is not.  The Jupyter Notebooks have the extension, .ipynb.

So anyway, the Jupyter Notebooks are not saved or formatted with python extensions.  There are no Jupyter Notebooks or Jupyter Labs ending with the .py extension.  That means Jupyter will not recognize an extension having .py, or .txt or .R or etc.... Jupyter opens, reads, and saves files having the .ipynb extension.

Jupyter Notebooks are an open document format based on JSON.

Jupyter can export in a number of different formats. Under the File tab, is the Export feature.  The last time I looked there were about 20 different export formats.  But there isn't a python or .py export format.  A Jupyter file can also be Downloaded. Also under the File tab is the Download feature.  This will download a standard text formatted JSON file.  JSON files are mostly unreadable unless you've spent years coding JSON.

So there's not much purpose in downloading the Jupyter file unless you are working on a remote server and cannot save your work at that site.  And it makes much more sense to save and copy the Jupyter file in its native Jupyter format - that means having the extension, .ipynb .  Then just open and use that file on another PC.

Hopefully this should clarify why Jupyter won't open any .py or .txt files.

Comment: ipynb does not stand for "iron ipython notebook" , it stands for "ipython notebook", where "ipython" was the original enhanced interactive shell for python

Comment: IronPython is an open-source implementation of the Python programming language which is tightly integrated with the.NET Framework. IronPython can use the.NET Framework and Python libraries, and other.NET languages can use Python code just as easily. Download IronPython 2.7.10 2.7.10 released on 2020-04-27
IronPython.net

Comment: i know what Iron Python is. Jupyter and IPython have nothing to do with it. And Jupyter Notebook or a Jupyter Lab server can definitely open .py files too as it has they have their text own editor built in. There's a lot that really misses the mark in this answer

Comment: The IPython Notebook is now known as the Jupyter Notebook. It is an interactive computational environment, in which you can combine code execution, rich text, mathematics, plots and rich media. For more details on the Jupyter Notebook, please see the Jupyter website.

Comment: Yes that's true. But that doesn't correct all of the misinformation in your answer

Comment: Go open an existing Jupyter file having the correct .ipynb extension.  Then go and save that Jupyter file with a .txt or .py extension.  Then you open the Jupyer console and try to open either of those files.   Good luck with that.

Comment: In a juptyer console or notebook, you can run python files with the `run` magic command.  that's the most basic think you can do:  https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run

Comment: This question had nothing to do with python magic.  This question was from a very confused newbie who doesn't understand how to correctly save a Jupyter file.

Comment: The OP was always running code in an ipython console and tried to save their interactive commands to a .py file, which is a perfectly valid workflow. With a .py file in the current directory, you can run the files directly from the ipython console or a notebook cell: https://imgur.com/a/Psd5sym

Comment: The OP said "I am new to JupiterLab and admit that I might have missed something important".  Further, the OP said, "put it in a JupiterLab text file and changed the extension to .py instead of .txt"       Enough said.  There is nothing mistaken or misleading about the answer I provided here.  And I completely stand by the response provided.  FYI.  Jupyter Lab does not run magic.

Comment: Jupyterlab provides access to a console. You can run .py files from that console. The issue is likely that the file was not saved in the directory the OP thought (and seriously -- scrape the stuff about Iron Python out of the answer. It has zero relevance here)